# Simply trying to paste the same string into a range of cells with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to paste the same string value into every row of an excel spreadsheet. I have defined the string within a loop, via my vba code:

```
    StickName = Left(myfile, 9)
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = StickName
```

It seems so simple to fill each row with the same value and I could do this via looping, writing into each cell until I reach the bottom row of the data, but there must be a more elegant solution. Is there a way to name a range (which would be a single column of data, from row x to y, within my loop) and fill an entire range with the same string?  Then re-define the range and the string value for each iteration of the loop?  I have searched on *fill range with value* and other similar searches and scoured the answers, but I don't see anything that addresses what I'm trying to do.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a range and then set the value of the range.

```
Dim r As Range
Dim s As String
s = "Hello World"
Set r = Sheets(1).Range("A1:A15")
r.Value = s
```

Comment: I used it without declaring and setting r. Simple code: Range("A1:A15).Value = s .

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any loops.  Say we want to fill rows **7** through**11** with some value:

```
Sub liroch()
   Dim StickName As String, myfile As String

   myfile = "abcdefghijklmnop"
   StickName = Left(myfile, 9)
   Rows("7:11").Value = StickName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare only your variable StickName and use this code:

```
StickName = Left(myfile, 9)
Range(Cells(startRow, StartColumn),Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)) = StickName
```

Comment: This is useful when range is used once. If you will need to work with the range object in your code many times, better is to declare range and use declared variable.